# 403 forbidden error for all local projects after updating php and apache

Tags: 12.04, server, permissions, apache2, php

I have 5 web app projects in my local machine with Ubuntu 12.04 installed on it. Everything was good, but today when I started a new project with symphony, I found that I should upgrade php to 5.4.x, so I did it and upgraded to apache2 too. After these updates I restarted my PC [for some reasons] and now I see a 403 forbidden page (from apache2 web-server) for all of my projects.
I didn't change permissions or the Apache virtual host configuration, nothing and nothing. Just after restart I see 403 forbidden!

- *I'm beginner in Ubuntu so if you want any information about users, groups, or... please say how can I find it for you, thanks*
- *I tried to change the whole web-root directory permission to `777` and change user:group to `www-data` or `root`, but nothing happened.*
- APACHE 2.4.6
  PHP 5.5.5-1
- example, this is the `thenetmoon` project and it was done with `symfony`, but apache can't access the web folder :
  [image]

Comment: With the packaged version of Apache an error like this would mean that www-data can't access that particular folder. You are using a non packaged version of Apache, thus I'd say you might have not configured it properly. Since you are a beginner I'd advise you to uninstall Apache 2.4.6 and install the packaged version (2.2.22).

Comment: @LuísdeSousa : thank you for quick answer, but i update it with `apt-get`. i can't understand whats the mean of `packaged version`. thank you so much

Comment: By "packaged version" I mean that available from the official repos. You can check it here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=apache&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all Good thing that you solved it.

Answer (score 3):

finally I found what happened. after reading about apache 2.4.*, I have changed `APACHE Configuration` file. so I added this line in `<Directory>` scope: 
    `Require all granted`
and after that, `sudo service apache2 restart` , and now everything goes fine.

Here is the Apache documentation relevant for this fix: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#access